# How to change Search permalink on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, search

Is it possible to change the Wordpress search permalink from:

> www.mydomain.com/search/my+result+keyword+term

to:

> www.mydomain.com/my-result/keyword-term

and to display the search page or any ideas for this.

Thank You.

Comment: Is the default not `?s=key+word`?

Answer (score 1):

Open the `searchform.php` within your theme folder and change the form action. You can of course even rebuild the whole search form if you like.

The wordpress codex has a usefull tutorial on this topic:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Comment: yes default is '?s=key+word?' change to /search/key-word and get to /key/word

Answer (score 1):

It's too late but could help others like me :)

Add following code into your functions.php file.

```
function wp_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_change_search_url' );

function wp_search_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^search/([^/]*)?', 'index.php?s=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'wp_search_rule' );
```